# Leer e imprimir un byte con read y write

Tags: java

Tengo este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int n = System.in.read();
            System.out.write(n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Si introduzco, por ejemplo, una 'a', el resultado es que no imprime nada. Porque no puedo imprimir el byte con write?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en que el objeto `System.out` es de tipo `PrintStream` el cual utiliza en su implementación una instancia de `BufferedOutputStream` para realizar las escrituras.

Los `BufferedOutputStream` no realizan una escritura física cada vez que invoca alguno de sus métodos `write()`, sino, que va almacenando los datos que se le han mandado a escribir hasta que se llene un buffer interno y es entonces cuando realiza la escritura física de los datos. El objetivo de este mecanismo es optimizar los procesos de escrituras físicas (por ejemplo en un disco duro) ya que estos son muy costosos. Si escribimos los datos byte a byte, nuestro programa tarda más en escribir el dato en si que en su funcionamiento interno.

Existe un modo de forzar las escrituras físicas, y es utilizando el método `flush()`, el cual obliga a escribir el contenido del buffer interno.

Si lees la documentación del método [`System.out.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-) puedes ver que solo se llamará al método `flush()` si el caracter que representa el parámetro es una salto de línea

> If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.

Por todo lo anterior es que no se escribe el caracter en la consola, porque se queda en el buffer interno del objeto `System.out` y al terminar la ejecución del programa este dato se pierde.

Para corregir el problema, solo debes agregar una llama al `flush()`

```
    try {
        int n = System.in.read();
        System.out.write(n);
        System.out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

o imprimir un salto de linea

```
    try {
        int n = System.in.read();
        System.out.write(n);
        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

o, utilizar el método `print()` o `println()` en vez de `write()`. Eso si, para utilizar alguno de estos debes castear tu entero a `char`

```
    try {
        int n = System.in.read();
        System.out.print((char) n);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado lo más claro posible y que lo hayas entendido.

Comment: Estás equivocado amigo, un casting se puede hacer en cualquier momento. Prueba el código tu mismo y me comentas.

Comment: Con System.in.read() y el posterior write funciona. Pero si pongo solamente el System.out.write(2) y System.out.flush() no imprime nada.

Comment: Porque el caracter cuyo valor numérico es 2, no es un caracter imprimible. En vez 2 escribe por ejemplo 81, para que veas que imprime una Q.

Answer (score 0):

Es normal que cuando le pasas una 'a' no imprima nada, ¿porqué? analicemos un poco tu código.

Para recoger por teclado un valor utilizas la siguiente línea:

```
int n = System.in.read();
```

Si te fijas, lo que recoges se lo estás asignando a un entero, con lo cual, es normal que al introducir una a de un error.

Al dar error y tener un try catch, lo que hace es entrar al catch (salta la línea de System.out.write(n)). 
Para que compruebes que es así, puedes poner dentro del catch, por ejemplo,

```
System.out.write("X");
```

Entonces, al introducir una letra, te pintará la X por pantalla.

Para evitar esto, lo que puedes hacer es, castear a char lo recogido por teclado y asignarlo a una variable de tipo char (sugerido por @lois6b).

Para realizarlo se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
char carRecogido = (char)System.in.read();
System.out.write(carRecogido);
```

Comment: `System.in.read()` devuelve un `int`. Si quisieras imprimir el caracter tendrias que castear a `(char)`

Comment: Hola he probado a poner fuera del catch este código         System.out.write(2);
Y no imprime nada. De hecho he quitado todo y he dejado sólo eso y no imprime nada. Raro no?

Comment: El método write() se utiliza para escribir bytes en el stream, es decir, para escribir datos que no pueden interpretarse como texto, como pueden ser los datos que componen un gráfico. Prueba a imprimir el dato con System.out.print o con System.out.println